# Method to solve this integral with algebraic and trigonometric terms

Tags: definite-integrals

I have the definite integral $\displaystyle\int_{0}^{\pi }\frac{x^2 \cos(x)}{(1+ \sin(x))^2}\,dx.$
Since there are both algebraic and trigonometric functions in the numerator, I don't know what substitution to make. Can someone tell the method of solving the above integral (and not the complete solution). I don't want the antiderivative, only the definite integral.

Note: The answer is $\pi(2-\pi).$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint. By integration by parts,
$$\int_{0}^{\pi }\frac{x^2 \cos(x)}{(1+\sin(x))^2}dx=-\left[\frac{x^2}{1+\sin (x)}\right]_0^{\pi}+2\int_{0}^{\pi }\frac{x }{1+\sin (x)}dx.$$
For the second integral use the symmetry $\sin(\pi-x)=\sin(x)$  and then let $t=\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)$.

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes I can do from here. I did not see that 'by parts method' in there. I was trying to do substitutions so hard.

Comment: @AbhijithSRaj Well done!

Comment: If you don't want to use integration by parts, first perform the change of variable $y=\pi-x$.  $\cos(\pi-x)=-\cos x$.

Comment: Are there some non-trivial consequences in terms of the Fourier series of $x^2$ and $\frac{\cos x}{(1+\sin x)^2}$?

Comment: @JackD'Aurizio Any magical hidden secret to reveal?

Comment: @RobertZ: no particular secret, just the fact that by considering such Fourier series one gets $\pi(2-\pi)$ as an explicit value for a $\phantom{}_3 F_2(\ldots;1)$, I guess.